# Python Sympy subs() no sustituye un producto escalar de vectores por una variable que lo represente

Tags: python, sympy

Estoy usando Python 3.7.2, con Sympy 1.3.

Mi problema consiste en hacer que en una expresión general (aquí la llamo "test1" y "test2"), el producto escalar "vporw" de vectores "v" y "w" que defino previamente a mano, se sustituya por una variable "p" que lo represente.

"deseo" es lo que pretendo obtener y "res2" (recomiendo correr el código para verlo, hay que deslizar la barra para verlo completo) es lo que obtengo cuando sustituyo en "test2".

Es frustrante que con "test1" sí tenga como resultado "deseo" y con "test2", haciendo lo mismo, salga "res2" diferente de "deseo". Es más "res2" sigue siendo igual que "test2"

```
import sympy as sp

# Construyendo los vectores manualmente

v0,v1,v2,v3 = sp.symbols('v0,v1,v2,v3')
w0,w1,w2,w3 = sp.symbols('w0,w1,w2,w3')

v = sp.Matrix([v0,v1,v2,v3])
w = sp.Matrix([w0,w1,w2,w3])

print("\n\nVector v:\n\n",v)
print("\n\nVector w:\n\n",w)

# Producto escalar de v por w

vporw = (v.T*w)[0]
print("\n\nProducto escalar de v por w que represento por \"p\":\n\n",vporw)

# Expresion test 1

x = sp.symbols('x')
test1 = 2*x*vporw+3*x**2
print("\n\nExpresion test 1:\n\n",test1)

# Expresion test 2 (equivale a test1)

test2 = test1.expand()
print("\n\nExpresion test 2:\n\n",test2)

# Resultado deseado

p = sp.symbols('p')
deseo = test1.subs(vporw,p)
print("\n\nResultado deseado:\n\n",deseo)

# Resultado obtenido en test2 (malo)

res2 = test2.subs(vporw,p)
print("\n\nResultado malo obtenido en test2:\n\n",res2)

print("\n\ndeseo==res2:",deseo==res2)
print("\n\ntest2==res2:",test2==res2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay que eligir si quieres la versión larga o la corta. Al momento que pones `vporw = (v.T*w)[0]` y `test1 = 2*x*vporw+3*x**2`, inmediatamente sympy cambia `vporw`por la expresión larga. Una manera de hacer lo que propones, es primero hacer el calculo con `vporw` como el simbolo 'p', y después sustituirlo con la expresión larga:

```py
import sympy as sp

v0,v1,v2,v3 = sp.symbols('v0,v1,v2,v3')
w0,w1,w2,w3 = sp.symbols('w0,w1,w2,w3')

v = sp.Matrix([v0,v1,v2,v3])
w = sp.Matrix([w0,w1,w2,w3])

print("\nVector v:\n",v)
print("\nVector w:\n",w)

# Producto escalar de v por w
vporw_expr = (v.T*w)[0]
print("\nProducto escalar de v por w que represento por \"p\":\n",vporw_expr)

# Expresion test 1
x = sp.symbols('x')
vporw = sp.symbols('p')
test1 = 2*x*vporw+3*x**2
print("\nExpresion test 1:\n",test1.simplify())

# Expresion test 2 (equivale a test1)
test2 = test1.expand()
print("\nExpresion test 2:\n",test2)

# Expresion test 3 (substitue p por el producto escalar)
test3 = test1.subs(vporw, vporw_expr)
print("\nExpresion test 3:\n",test3)
```